# What is the proper way in Perl to dynamically and repeatedly load code?

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that needs to execute some known-at-runtime number of sub-scripts sequentially, but it would be helpful/convenient if the sub-scripts shared the state info of the main program (the sub-script does not need to change the state info, though). The main script would be called with the name of a directory of ZIP files, and each ZIP file would have in it a perl module/library/script, presumably with the same name, but that doesn't need to be the case.

Some things I've thought of trying:

1. have each sub-script provide a RunMe.pm module which would get loaded, used, then unloaded (via manipulating `%INC` -- ugh)
2. fork for each sub-script, `require` or `use` RunMe.pm, do whatever, then exit
3. write a perl library instead and `do` or `eval` the library (though I think using `do` would still require manipulating `%INC`)

In Java I would have a class implement an interface and have a factory to create all of them, though I wouldn't know the names of the implementing classes at compile time, so I'd resort to Class.forName().

All of this is kind of on the ugly side and is leading me to reconsider the design idea entirely, which may be the correct answer here.

Comment: why the manipulating %INC?  because you are running each one more than once? or for some other reason?

Comment: I was thinking they'd all be named the same thing. I'll amend the question.

Comment: Upon reflection I asked a poorly worded question; Hobbs has answered the question as worded below. I will post a new question to meet my needs and cross-link it here.

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230644/perl-design-pattern-for-running-arbitrary-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the zip files truly necessary? If we can dispense with the zip files then there are a bunch of well-tested tools that we can use — chiefly [Module::Pluggable](http://p3rl.org/Module::Pluggable) to look in a directory tree for Perl modules matching a given name prefix, load them, and return them. In place of Java interfaces you can use Moose [roles](http://p3rl.org/Moose::Role) which function like both interfaces and mixins, meaning that you can enforce that each module provides certain methods, and also provide each one with some shared behavior for free. Roles are also introspectable, so you can use them to distinguish scriptlets/plugins that should be run in different ways.

If the zip files are really important, I can still see a way to make the whole thing work using `@INC` hooks (thankfully Module::Pluggable recently added support to play more nicely with those), but the complexity begins to approach "here are my consulting rates" levels.

Answer (score 0):

First off you are going to have to extract the code from the zip files. Using Archive::Extract you can dump the extracted files into a known directory.

If you set your include path to this directory using the *lib* pragma and if you make the files in the zip file Perl module files you can load the file into your main program with a 
*require Package::Name* statement. This is a runtime statement.
If you want to load in a second module with the same name then you will have yo clear out the modules stash and remove it from %INC.

A function like

```
sub unload_module {
    my $module = shift;
    my $inc_key = $module;

    # Convert $inc_key into the correct format for %INC
    $inc_key =~ s/::/\//g;
    $inc_key .= '.pm';

    # Remove from %INC
    delete $INC{$inc_key};

    # Clear the Stash
    delete %{"$module::"};
}
```

This assumes that you did not want to import any thing into the main packages name space

Comment: It's not necessary to unpack the zip files to disk; [ex::lib::zip](https://metacpan.org/pod/ex::lib::zip) is an example of how you can load modules from a zip using an `@INC` hook (although it really needs removal support to be more useful).